# Ethers Provider CORS error with JsonRPCProvider inside of react application

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js, binance-smart-chain

Having an issue where my ethers provider is giving me a cors issue for just read only functions. I am not even creating any transactions or anything. I have tried changing nodes and different rpcs but it doesn't help. You can find an image of the errors I get below.
Heres my provider code which I import to all the function pages and heres an example of a function below that. Very basic stuff.

This is a basic react application that is displaying some information about a Binance smart chain token.

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://speedy-nodes-nyc.moralis.io/1c2baaae7c0d11120337ddc1/bsc/mainnet"
);

export default provider;
```

Example function:

```
export const getReflectionLive = async () => {
  try {
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, tokenAbi, provider);

    let rate = await getDeadRate();
    
    tokenContract.on("Transfer", async (from, to, value, event2) => {
      console.log("New Dead Balance addition", (value / 10 ** 9) * 0.05 * rate);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error --> ${error}`);
  }
};
```

All my Error Codes:

[Error Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVWDd.png)

```
×
Unhandled Rejection (Error): could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.4.4)

Access to fetch at 'https://speedy-nodes-nyc.moralis.io/1c2baaae7c0d11120337ddc1/bsc/mainnet' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

POST https://speedy-nodes-nyc.moralis.io/1c2baaae7c0d11120337ddc1/bsc/mainnet net::ERR_FAILED


×
Unhandled Rejection (Error): missing revert data in call exception (error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":52,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"missing trie node 264c5265b90a8eb574898445f88321e330c126156794b45cfec08ede5c80f693 (path )\"}}","error":{"code":-32000},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_call\",\"params\":[{\"to\":\"0xc748673057861a797275cd8a068abb95a902e8de\",\"data\":\"0x70a08231000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000dead\"},\"0xbc4921\"],\"id\":52,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"}, data="0x", code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.4.4)
```

Comment: That's not something you do from the frontend, you don't want to expose that endpoint.

Comment: okay so I add it as env variable? why would end point stop though? its reading off of a node

Comment: No you only do things like that in backend. For frontend use MetaMask.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you know what you are doing (security!) - and in case you have an Apache server running. You might add the following to your site configuration in Apache:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
```

Do not forget to enable Apache's header module.

Background:
Ethers.js requires to have in "cross domain/port/server" operation some access rights in order to work in every supported Browser. This forces that the webserver sends all required and allows everything.